# Canceling a "submit" button execution

Tags: javascript, html

I have a submit button in HTML for a form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" id="execute" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to apply javascript for a confirm window, and if the user clicks cancel, the submit will not execute. How do I do that?

Comment: You might want to look into using unobstrusive javascript for modern-day practices.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie How is that relevant to the OP? They don't have **any** Javascript yet.

Comment: @millimoose just to become familiar with the term and the advantages it affords.  not germane to anything other than the OP's growth in manipulating technology to his highest benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lazy and easy way.

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you want to submit the form?'">
```

A nicer approach would of course be to put this into a script-file and binding the event onload instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just `return false` on click event of button

```
 <input type="submit" id="execute" onclick="return false;"/>
```

If you want to use `confirm`

```
 <input type="submit" id="execute" onclick="return confirm("Your message");"/>
```

Comment: How about the confirm window?

Comment: @Majed, `return confirm("Something")`

Comment: If you use `onlick` on the button it won't catch the submit if the users presses Enter-key in the textfield. Better to use the `onsubmit`-event to be sure to always catch it.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="execute"  />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function check() {
    if (confirm('submit?')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UJ7Q4/

**JS-jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm('submit?')) {
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="execute" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rqc5A/

Comment: Why would you call `e.preventDefault()` and then redo the submit afterwards instead of just doing `e.preventDefault()` if the confirm fails?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren sure why not :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` to test the `confirm()` results:

```
function checkConfirm() {
    var c = confirm("Your message here...");

    if(c) {
        //User clicked OK, do stuff here, maybe even submit the form
        document.forms['id'].submit();
    } else {
        //User clicked cancel, just quit.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then add the function inline to your submit button.

```
<input type="submit" id="execute" onclick="checkConfirm();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" id="execute" 
onclick="if !(confirm('your confirmation message')) return false;"/>
```

Comment: Why use an `if`-statement there?

Answer (score 0):

How about giving an id to your form

```
<form id="formname">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="execute" />
</form>
```

and using

```
var form = document.getElementById('formname');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    var question = confirm('Really submit the form ?');
    if (!question){e.preventDefault();}
}, false);
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/k7XuV/